# Expected ; after top level declarator, error in xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I am working with this [utils.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavcodec_2utils_8c_source.html) file in xcode, which has the following:

```
 #if FF_API_AVCODEC_OPEN
    int attribute_align_arg avcodec_open(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVCodec *codec)
    {
        return avcodec_open2(avctx, codec, NULL);
    }
```

It's causing an `Expected ; after top level declarator`, error (during build) in xcode at this line: `int attribute_align_arg avcodec_open(....`

Why? and what should I do to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like `attribute_align_arg` has not been defined. You need to include the appropriate header file which according to Google is `libavutil/internal.h`

Comment: If @CaptainObvlious's solutionn isn't it, what are the lines above the code you've provided?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious, The `libavutil/internal.h` is included in xcodes header paths. The error is not about definition of an object, nor an unfound `.h` file. It's about (I think) that xcode is expecting a `;` right after the `int attribute_align_arg` in the statement above.

Comment: @cube which would mean is either not defined or is something that expands to a valid identifier name. Whatever the problem is it's being interpreted as a variable declaration.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I ran into this error when using the auto completion.

When inserting the parameter of a function, XCode will insert placeholders that need to be edited but show as completely valid C++ in the GUI.

It took me some hours until I checked my file in another editor, revealing that instead of the expected:

> void func(int a)

XCode had actually inserted

> void func(<#int a#>)

In the XCode editor the parameter shows as `int a` with a light blue background, so it isn't easy to spot as the source of the compiler error.

Comment: That's unbelievable! It did not look like a place holder

Comment: I did a cut n' paste and got something similar. There must have been some special characters in there. I deleted, retyped, and the error went away :)

Comment: There is some kind of a place holder, as the arguments are placed inside a colored box. Anyway, I did not realize the problem when I had it too.

Comment: Wow. What the .....!!! This is unbelievable. A professional tool behaving like this.
Zord, good find! thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just had the same problem happen in Codelite.

Answer (score 8):

I got a similar error in xcode for the following code:

```
#ifndef Parser_hpp
#define Parser_hpp

#include <string>
std::string getTitle();

#endif /* Parser_hpp */
```

The reason was that the code had to be wrapped with C++ preprocessor directives. Like so:

```
#ifndef Parser_hpp
#define Parser_hpp
#if defined __cplusplus

#include <string>
std::string getTitle();

#endif /* __cplusplus */
#endif /* Parser_hpp */
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after moving a class to a dynamic library but leaving the old import around. Commenting out the old import resolved the issue (but it wasn't the first thing I looked for as the dynamic library import was earlier and also showed an error).