# makefile with files from different folders (for C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, g++

I'm trying to compile a C++ test file, which is supposed to compile from files that are in adjacent folders in the project file structure. I have the following:

```
Project/TestFiles/makefile
Project/TestFiles/test.cpp
Project/OtherFiles/my_stuff.cpp
Project/OtherFiles/my_stuff.hpp
```

For the compile, I'm trying to leave the `my_stuff.o` file in the `OtherFiles` folder, so if I have other `makefiles`, they dont have to recompile separate versions each.

My `makefile` looks as follows:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wcomment -Werror -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic

run: test.out

test.out: test.cpp catchMain.cpp ../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

my_stuff.o: ../OtherFiles/my_stuff.cpp ../OtherFiles/my_stuff.hpp
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

I thought for a while that this setup worked, but then I started getting some weird problems and couldn't compile. For instance, having a `static const map` produced `error: expected ';' after top level declarator`. At first, Internet seemed to indicate that Mac compilers sometimes aren't able to compile `static const map`s with member initialisation lists (which it also complained about, if I removed the `static const` part). However, when I commented out everything to do with the `std::map` (leaving the `makefile` as described above) OR placed all files in the same folder (rewriting both the `makefile` as well as the `#include`s in `test.cpp`), everything is ok, but I'd like to use both `std::map`s AND the chosen file structure. Oh, and removing the extra warning flags doesn't work either.

Any ideas how I could do that?

## Edit

`my_stuff.hpp`:

```
namespace my_stuff {
   void function();
}
```

`my_stuff.cpp`:

```
#include "my_stuff.hpp"
#include <map>

namespace my_stuff {
  static const std::map<char, char> the_map {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}};
  void my_function() {
    // map stuff
  }
}
```

The test part is both a vanilla `catchMain.cpp`:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "../../Catch2/catch.hpp" //which is outside the project specifics
```

and the actual tests, `my_tests.cpp`:

```
#include "../../Catch2/catch.hpp"
#include "../OtherFiles/my_stuff.hpp"
#include <map>

SCENARIO("", "") {
  GIVEN("") {
    WHEN("") {
      THEN("") {
        my_function();
        // Other stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The target `test.out` will never find required `../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o`. The target `my_stuff.o: ` must be `../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o`.

Comment: *Any ideas how I could do that?* Show the code and the complete error messages.

Comment: Do you have makefiles in the subdirectories too? If so, you should use them from the top makefile too. `make -C subdir [target]`

Comment: do you have to use make? you might find cmake easier

Comment: There, added some code.

Comment: @S.M. I've tried that as well, but that gives:
`clang: error: no such file or directory: '../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o'`

Comment: Maybe this topic is your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129698/expected-after-top-level-declarator-error-in-xcode

Comment: @TedLyngmo I dont as of now, because I am currently setting up my tests and prefer if they are independent.

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, I dont, but I have never used cmake, but maybe that would solve the problem.

Comment: @S.M. Thanks! I currently am using VIM, but I opened it and had a look in Atom,   without finding anything odd (well, around the troubled parts, that is; I havent resorted to scouring the project manually for malplaced whitespaces just yet)

Comment: I thought there might be old `.o` files lying about, and deleted all of  them and tried again. What's even more strange, is that I get the error and cant compile with a member initialisation list as `static const std::map<char, char> the_map {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}};`, but when I remove the initialisation list and type `static const std::map<char, char> the_map;`, everything works (well, save my tests, of course...). This is **without** the suggested change to `../OtherFiles/`, btw. I read some Mac compilers are unable to do member initialisation lists; can that be the error somehow? Weird...

Answer (score 0):

As @S.M. pointed out, you must change the `my_stuff.o` rule, but you must change the recipe as well as the target, so that it will actually build the thing you want:

```
../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o: ../OtherFiles/my_stuff.cpp ../OtherFiles/my_stuff.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

More generally, you must understand the language before you attempt to manipulate it. Swapping patches in and out to see what works is a very inefficient way to write code.

Comment: While I don't claim to be an expert, I thought I understood it well enough for my use cases. I'm also not swapping bits and pieces at random so much as troubleshooting the issue. I'm quite confused as to why it seems to break down when I add certain code OR when I place it all in the same. Your suggested solution unfortunately doesn't work and gives `clang: error: no such file or directory: '../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o'`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @GreatName: What else is it doing? Does it give any other messages? Does it build `../OtherFiles/my_stuff.o'?

Comment: It seems it uses a different compiler in different cases with the `makefile`. When I split up the file into separate adjacent folders, it uses (I'm guessing) an older one, which does not have the latest features. If this is accurate, how can I force make to use a certain compiler or version more explicitly than I already have? I use a Mac terminal, `G++ --version`: `Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2); Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0; Thread model: posix`