# Xcode8 IOS C++ not being Recognized (worked under xcode 7)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode8

Upgraded to xcode 8 (OSX EL Capitan 10.11.6) All of a sudden it appears it does not recognize the C++ code (.hpp / .cpp) Getting strange errors, CPP common header files not found, "class" keyword not recognized in the .hpp file. Have tried a bunch of changes involving adding compiler flags and linking against libstdc++.

It was working fine under xcode 7... 
Anyone? Thanks in advance

Finally..... Here is the answer, after stumbling upon someone else with the same problem...

[Include <string> not found compile error in Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325853/include-string-not-found-compile-error-in-xcode-4-2)

Way down like the very last answer (Ironically no one voted up...)
From "Volomike" He Wrote:

> "There's a quirk in XCode. I noticed it in 7.3. Most projects
>   recognize .mm files and the STL, while one project I had did not. The
>   fix was that I had to click on the top-left project icon, then click
>   Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries > and add in
>   AppKit.framework. Next, I had to click Targets > Build Settings >
>   search on "Compile Sources", and set it to "Objective C++" on all
>   possible columns. Then, do a Clean and then a Build from the Product
>   menu. This compiled properly then. Then, go back to that Compile
>   Sources again and set it back to "According to File Type" on all
>   possible columns. Then, click Build from the Product menu again. At
>   that point, it compiled properly and allowed me to utilize the
>   "according to file type" option, which I like better.

Oh, and if doing Cocoa stuff, don't forget to add the following header in your files:"

Comment: Can you copy and paste some of the error messages here?

Comment: Exactly what I said they were... <string> 'string' file not found, if I comment that out, the next statement is the 'class' keyword "Did you mean 'Class?' Like I said, it's not recognizing the the .hpp & .cpp files. They worked b4 under xcode 7, AND YES the file that uses this CPP code IS ".mm" I've even tried deleting and recreating them through the add new "C++"  file.                                                                                 This is exactly why I do NOT Like using any Automated IDE's.... GIVE ME A MAKE File and I can trace everything out

Comment: Add `libc++.dll` file in **link binary with libraries** section.

Comment: Look at File Inspector and double check that Xcode thinks they are Objective C++ files (yes, even though you have tagged them as .mm). I use heavy C++ in most of my projects and did not experience such a thing. You can also check your build logs and see if you see `objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler`. You'll need to expand lines to see that.

Comment: @NpC0mpl3t3 I meant to paste the *exact* message with filenames, file paths, etc. Also, it would be useful if you pasted the exact command that Xcode output which generated the error.

Comment: @ Mobile Ben  The File Inspector indicates the .hpp as C++ default Header,  .cpp and default C++ source, and mm file as Object C++ source

Comment: @MobileBen - but thanks for the 'hint' on this build log, it looks like the build command line...  (I'm not an xcode person)

Comment: You will need to list your LLVM/C++ settings. It is behaving like it is not compiling with C++.  It's a curious thing. My current project is actually pretty complex with a lot of files and my conversion when fine when building.

Comment: I've tried 3 different C++ settings, currently it's set to: Language Dialect: GNU++11 [-std-gnu++11] and C++ Standard Library libc++

Comment: OK.... That hint on the build log actually helped me out... thanks... Once I ran the command line using "objective-c++" I was able to gleen this... "error: invalid argument '-std=gnu99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'" so once I removed the bad compiler argument, it now will compile ---- ON THE COMMAND LINE .... So somewhere in the LLVM settings it needs to be using the object-c++ compiler.... I'm not sure where in this IDE  I can set this..?

Comment: This is the C Dialect. Min is set to `GNU99 [-std=gnu99]`

Comment: My other settings are `GNU++14` and `libc++`. I just recently switched to c++14 only because I realized Xcode 8 is supporting it now. I was running c++11 fine with Xcode 8

Comment: Yea, I know what the -std-gnu99 means, but I have no idea why it's only using the "object-c" compiler argument when it compiles.... This is my major problem with any IDE's.... When stuff goes wrong, you can waste an enormous amount of time, just trying figure out what it's it doing and why...

Comment: What's the xml file that stores these build settings? Is there something else  like this Info.plist..?

Comment: I wasn't insinuating you didn't know what it means. `GNU99 [-std=gnu99]` is how it is written in the IDE, I'm just trying to be concise to help you. You haven't been terribly forthcoming with information, just mainly how much you hate IDEs. Do you use source control and did you commit prior to upgrading to Xcode 8. If so, look at your diffs and see what changed. Project file is actually a file called `project.pbxpro`j which is in the `.xcodeproj` folder (it appears to be the project file, but it is really a folder).

Comment: @MobileBen -- I understand no offense taken... thank you.... Like I said, nothings changes other than the xcode version...  And when I run the correct command line -- it builds.... mmmm..... but thanks I'll diff that project.pbxpro with an older version....