# Xcode noticed the error of “ 'string' file not found” when I compile the c++ and object-c?

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I have tried to modify the configuration in the screenshot below, and I have tried various combinations.

[image]

I have wasted a lot of time to check this mistake, so please help me！

In addition, the  suffix of C++ files is changed to **.mm**. But it's still working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does the prompt to *enter image description here* appear in the middle of a word? What is the connection between the image and your problem? Have you been able to compile before? What changed?

Comment: sorry，I will resubmit the question，thank you！this question will be delete。

Comment: We don't see your code and we don't see compiler messages, that is, the question contains **no** relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see all the code. 
However, I believe this is a duplicate of [Include <string> not found compile error in Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325853/include-string-not-found-compile-error-in-xcode-4-2) so hopefully you can get the solution there.

Basically, you are probably using 'string' in the code, but not included libs that know what 'string' is.

.m and. mm are fine as they are essentially Objective C versions of .h and. cpp

Comment: I have do it follow the link before, still error now.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you much more without seeing the rest of the code in that file tbh.