# Why Xcode gives error 'string' file not found?

Tags: c++, swift, interop, wrapper

I am trying to interop with basic C++ method in Swift. But Xcode gives me an error when I build the project;

```
'string' file not found
```

I have researched this issue on StackOverflow but every solution and answers didn't solve my problem. And I started to think that what if I use libstdc++ rather than libc++. Then I found that libstdc++ was removed with Xcode 10. I found the files on Github and apply it to appropriate file directories. And that did not do much either. Did you guys encounter with this kind of problem before?

This is my header file.

```
#ifndef CPPTest_hpp
#define CPPTest_hpp

#include <string>

std::string saySomething();

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    int returnNumber();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif CPPTest_hpp
```

This is the cpp file.

```
#include "CPPTest.hpp"

std::string saySomething()
{
    return "Welcome to C++";
}

int returnNumber()
{
    return 10;
}
```

This is where I expose header to Swift

```
#include "CPPTest.hpp"
```

After all, When I build the project. It gives me an error like;

> 'string' file not found

Why does this error occur?

By the way, it works when I use integer as return type and its appropriate implementation in cpp file.

Comment: @Ruks I tried that thread and did not solve my problem.

Comment: There is no interop between Swift and C++ as far as I know.

Comment: @molbdnilo Actually, I watched a tutorial about it. You can interop between Swift and C++ via bridging. That was my inspiration 

Comment: @YektaSarıoğlu The "bridge" must be a plain (Objective-) C interface.

Comment: @molbdnilo It is. And it works if I use int rather than String. I tested it.

Comment: Try this answer, I believe it is related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950436/8447312

Comment: @emrepun I tried it. That didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you look at this thread as well? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106114

Try `gsmalley`s answer.

Comment: @YektaSarıoğlu `#include <string>`and  `std::string` are not (Objective-) C. You can't use any C++ classes (or other features).

Comment: Found any solution to this ??